# When typing, automatically transform SPC SPC into PERIOD SPC SPC

Tags: key-bindings, capitalization

I would like the period at the end of a sentence to be added automatically when two spaces are typed (similar to how typing works in iPhones).

I use two spaces between sentences, so the transformation I would like to happen would look like this:

```
b l a h SPC SPC  -->  b l a h . SPC SPC
```

I plan to use this along with the auto-capitalize mode.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
(defun freaky-space ()
  (interactive)
  (cond ((looking-back "\\(?:^\\|\\.\\)  +")
         (insert " "))
        ((eq this-command
             last-command)
         (backward-delete-char 1)
         (insert ".  "))
        (t
         (insert " "))))

(define-key text-mode-map " " 'freaky-space)
```

Comment: Great.  One nice thing about this solution is that it takes into account the context (e.g., only insert a period if there's no period already there).

Answer (score 7):

[Keychords](http://www.emacswiki.org/KeyChord) would let you do this. You would also want `SPC SPC` to be translated to `. SPC` only when you type them fast enough. That's exactly what keychords would do. After installing `key-chord` you can define something like this:

```
(key-chord-define-local (kbd "SPC SPC") (lambda () (insert ". ")))
```

Comment: I tried exactly that with key-chord. It makes it so that typing a space between words is very slow. I guess it's waiting to see if you'll type a second space. I turned it off.

Comment: @incandescentman Yes, you are right. Using a one-key keychord on a common key does have this issue. You could try tweaking `key-chord-one-key-delay` to your liking.

Comment: The fastest I could get it to recognize discrete key presses was `(setq key-chord-one-key-delay 0.11)`, which still creates a long lag when typing a single space.